# How to do if else condition in laravel when else case is need to skip

Tags: mysql, laravel

Actually I don't want to check the `else` condition of below code and status 1 is compulsory only in the case of co_order_paymenttype_id is 1(  both  are in same table)
this is my code

```
  DeliveryOrder::where('cb_order_type' , 0)->whereRaw('IF (`co_order_paymenttype_id` = 1, 
 `status` = 1,`status` = 0)')->paginate($page);
```

Comment: I seriously did not understand what you want. But you can't remove else statement from if statement.

Comment: if you dont need `else` then you don't need to use `if` it will be just another `where`

Answer (score 1):

Ok as I commented above if you don't need `else` then it's not the case that you should use `if` statment.

you shoud use only where to get your needs and to make that in laravel you need to use [advanced where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres)

```
DeliveryOrder::where('cb_order_type' , 0)->where(function($query){
   $query->where('co_order_paymenttype_id', 1)
         ->where('status' = 1);
})->paginate($page);
```

if you need to and any other condition you need to change it as you want, you can add another `orWhere` for expample.
please read the documentaion in the link above.